# Redirect via htaccess in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having some problem regarding redirection in php, I used .htaccess for this but didn't succeed 
**what I have is following 2 urls :**

```
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/USERNAME/348

http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/USERNAME
```

**What I want here is :**

1) if request came from

```
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/USERNAME/111
```

then it should go to:

```
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/index.php
```

2) If request came from

```
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/USERNAME
```

then it should go to:

```
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/detail.php
```

**What I tried :**

```
RewriteRule /(\w+)$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule /(\w+)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule /$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
```

Didn't succeed after this it works fine for index but not for detail page, Please help guys thanks for your time in advance

Randheer

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues here.  First is the order and specificity of the matching.

**First, a big gotcha for regex learners:** `\w` (shorthand "word" character class) is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` . . . note the digits and underscore included!

Assuming that all of the IDs in the last fragment are *only numeric* and that usernames are all some mix of alpha, numberic, and/or underscore, you can just change the order of matching and use the `\d` (digit) character class first:

```
RewriteRule /(\d+)$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule /(\w+)$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

That should cover your two examples.

You didn't outline a use case for the third rule, so I'm not exactly sure which URLs you're applying that to or how it would need to change.  Here are some observation though:

1. You should place the `RewriteCond` lines *before* the `RewriteRule` they apply to. (Keep in mind that the expression of rewrite rule is actually checked first, then the conditions.)
2. Right now, the `RewriteRule` expression would match anything ending with a trailing slash that isn't a real file.
3. Also checking that it isn't index.php is redundant to `!-f`.  And since you're matching with a trailing slash, you probably actually want to check that it's not a directory (versus file) using `!-d`
4. The `RewriteCond` expression is trying to capture within a negated expression (so it will never capture anything, or match for that matter since the effective expression is the same as the one in the rule, `/$`)

If you're trying to allow for a trailing slash on the username above, you could just add to what's already there:

```
RewriteRule /(\d+)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /(\w+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If your use case for the third rule is something different, or if those `RewriteCond` expressions were for a different rule below what you pasted, feel free to edit the question with the details and I can update my answer to address that case as well.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. 
I tried above option but it didn't work 
the major problem is with the following url : 

http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/USERNAME

it is not redirecting to "detail.php" page

Comment: @RandheerSinghChouhan A few things: 1. Does the other rule work correctly? If not, does `RewriteEngine On` appear before these lines? 2. Which version of the code above did you try? 3. Which path is this .htaccess file located in?  Additionally, no redirect should occur inside the browser with these rules—their purpose is to *rewrite* the request to point the intended file within Apache (transparently to the user).  If you want to issue a client-side redirect (e.g. response code 301 or 302), you need to use the `[R]` or `[R=301]` flag accordingly.